# what does the colon in asm volatile() mean

Tags: c++, assembly, gcc, inline-assembly

i'm not sure if i accidently modified the code a bit, but here it is (i'm a beginner to inline assembly, but quite used to assembly in a different file):-

```
void out8(uint16 port, uint8 data) {asm volatile("outb %0, %1" : "dN"(port) : "a"(data));}
void out16(uint16 port, uint16 data) {asm volatile("outw %0, %1" : "dN"(port) : "a"(data));}
void out32(uint16 port, uint32 data) {asm volatile("outl %%eax, %%dx" : "dN"(port) : "a"(data));}
```

previously it gave no error but now it is. but can anyone correct this code? and also, tell me on what basis is the colon separating the values, the "dN" and the "a" in the colon separated areas,
the "%0" and "%1" in the inline assembly, why are those variables "port" and "data" in brackets next to the "a" and "dN" and what is the difference between "%*[reg]*" and "%%*[reg]*" so that i can solve problems like these later when i get them. (tl;du (u stands for understand) the manual page for inline extended assembly is japanese (you know what i mean, right?))

---

**[SOLVED]**

used :-

```
void out(uint16 port, uint8 data) {asm volatile("outb %1, %0" :: "dN"(port), "a"(data));}
void out(uint16 port, uint16 data) {asm volatile("outw %1, %0" : : "dN"(port), "a"(data));}
// Warning, this one's still unsafe, even though it compiles
void out(uint16 port, uint32 data) {asm volatile("outl %%eax, %%dx" : : "dN"(port), "a"(data));}
```

(Warning to future readers: `outl` still has a bug, see the answer(s).)

Comment: When asking questions involving build errors, *always* include the actual errors you get. And preferably a proper [mre] to show us as well.

Comment: And how much of [the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/) have you read? What parts of its [inline assembly documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html#Using-Assembly-Language-with-C) regarding the issue don't you understand?

Comment: Read the manual for the syntax, obviously.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html.  They're all broken from putting the port number as an output (after the first `:`, not 2nd). Also, you separately broke `out32`. A `"dN"` constraint allows the compiler to pick DX or an immediate, but you don't reference the `%0` first operand instead always assuming it will pick DX.   So an optimized build that inlines for `out32(12, 0x1234)` would *not* have put the port number in DX, but with no `%0` in the template the `$12` doesn't get substituted anywhere into the compiler-generated asm.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline-assembly for links to guides other than the official docs.  If you're confused by the fact that `out` has two "inputs", think of it like a store instruction.  Two pieces of data come from the CPU (the data and the address), resulting in a store to memory.  Unlike a load or `in` where the load instruction writes a register, and the compiler needs to know where that result is placed.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because it can be answered by reading the documentation on [extended inline assembly](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).

Comment: @fuz: same, but the comments I'd written basically amounted to an answer so I ended up posting one anyway.  I somewhat regret spending the time doing that, and IDK how much value it will have to future readers vs. existing Q&As like [How do you explain gcc's inline assembly constraints for the IN, OUT instructions of i386?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50769146)

Comment: Don't edit answers into the question; post them separately so they can be voted on separate from the question, and aren't given a special place relative to other answers for future readers.  Also, you missed the 2nd section of my answer about the other bug in `outl`, the one that makes it unsafe even though it compiles.  (Actually I'm just going to roll back that edit, instead of add warnings to that answer stuffed into the question.)

Comment: @PeterCordes i didn't get any error while compiling

Comment: As I said, GNU C inline asm makes it very easy to write code that compiles but doesn't accurately describe the template to the compiler/optimizer via the constraints.  So it will break for some combinations of surrounding code and compiler options.  "It compiles" is necessary but *far* from sufficient for inline asm to be correct.

Comment: @PeterCordes can i know what is the trouble with outl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manual documents the syntax (and much other info; it's worth reading these days since it's gotten a lot of improvements over the years).  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html.

```
asm asm-qualifiers ( AssemblerTemplate 
                 : OutputOperands 
                 [ : InputOperands
                 [ : Clobbers ] ])
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline-assembly for links to guides other than the official docs.  Especially https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm which describes some pitfalls.

---

**You have `"dN"(port)` in the outputs section, but it's actually an input** (no `=` or `+` : [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Modifiers.html)).  And yes, the I/O port number should be an input: it's something the asm statement needs to get from the surrounding code of your program, not something the asm statement is providing back to your program.  So the compiler needs to know how to provide it to the asm statement, not collect it.

If you're confused by the fact that `out` has two "inputs", think of it like a store instruction.  Two pieces of data come from the CPU (the data and the address), resulting in a store to memory.  Unlike a load or `in` where the load instruction writes a register, in which case the compiler needs to know where that result is placed.

You also have the `%0, %1` operands in the wrong order for the order of the constraints, assuming this is for AT&T syntax (not `gcc -masm=intel`).  Named constraints like `[port] "dN" (port)` to match `%[port]` in the template would avoid that. https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/out is `out dx/imm8, AL/AX/EAX` in Intel syntax, or `out  %al/%ax/%eax, %dx/$imm8` in AT&T.

---

##### Also, you separately broke `out32()` in another way.

A `"dN"` constraint allows the compiler to pick DX or an immediate for that variable (if its value is known at compile time and is [small enough](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html)).

But your asm template string doesn't reference that `%0` first operand, instead hard-coding the `%%dx` register name, which is only correct if the compiler picks DX.

An optimized build that inlines `out32(0x80, 0x1234)` would *not* have put the port number in DX with preceding instructions, instead picking the `N` (unsigned 8-bit) constraint because it's cheaper.  But no `$0x80` gets filled in anywhere in the final compiler-generated asm because there's no `%0` in the template for the compiler to expand.

Think of asm template strings like printf format strings that the compiler expands, before passing on the whole asm  to the assembler. (Including compiler-generated instructions before and after, from compiling other C statements, and for some constraints like `"r"` or `"d"` to put a C variable or expression's value into a register if it wasn't already there.)

`%%` is just a literal `%`, so if you want to hard-code an AT&T register name like `%eax`, you use `%%eax` in the Extended Asm template.

You can see that asm on https://godbolt.org/.  (Use "binary" mode to see if the resulting compiler-generated asm will actually assemble.  That's not guaranteed when using inline asm.)

For working `outb` / etc. macros, many codebases define them, and I think some libc implementations have inline wrappers, like maybe MUSL, maybe also glibc.  If you just want working code, don't try to write your own when you don't know inline asm.

Related:

- [How do you explain gcc's inline assembly constraints for the IN, OUT instructions of i386?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50769146/how-do-you-explain-gccs-inline-assembly-constraints-for-the-in-out-instruction) breaks down an `inb` wrapper function.
- [C inline asm for x86 in / out port I/O has operand-size mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52355247/c-inline-asm-for-x86-in-out-port-i-o-has-operand-size-mismatch) the size of register picked for `"d"` depends on the C type width, and has to be 16-bit because `in`/`out` specifically use DX.  (I/O address space is 64k, unlike memory address space.)
- [GCC Inline Assembly 'Nd' constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791997/gcc-inline-assembly-nd-constraint/32792177#32792177)
- **https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html  The manual.  Read it**.  Inline asm is easy to get subtly but dangerously wrong; do not rely on trial and error / "seems to work".
- https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm.  (Or in this case, find some known-good in/out wrapper functions in a libc header or something and use them instead of writing your own, if you don't know inline asm.)
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-syntax/info

Comment: "Read the manual, obviously" is conversational and not relevant to this post. Citing manuals is constructive. This answer is ripe for fixing.

Comment: @Kröw: Yes, thanks, not a constructive tone for the start of an answer.  Fixed.  Now it still conveys the idea that reading the manual is an obvious first step, but without trying to make people feel stupid for not having done so.